# extract many zip files but set different destination directories following the content file extensions with unzip cmd

Tags: command-line, unzip

I have many .zip files, each file contains many different file with different extensions, e.g: **.c**, **.py**, **.java** and **.cpp** etc.

I am only interesting to extract all file with .py or .java from these zip files.
I am using this command
`unzip -d myDestinationFolder/ "Na*.zip" "*.py" "*.java"`

It unzips my wanted files with specific extensions to the directory myDestinationDirectory.

Is there a way to mkdir automatically following the wanted file types then unzips them to the corresponding directory?

So all **.py** files are extracted to a directory called **py**, **.java** to another directory called **java** etc.

Comment: `unzip archive-name "*.py" -d dist-name`

Comment: I wann a to extract not only one filetype but many at once

Comment: Unix/Linux philosophy is to do the simple thing without mistakes. You can do this which you prefer. #1 extract everything sort after, #2 extract only sorted files. `unzip archive-name "*.py" -d dist-name1 && unzip archive-name "*.java" -d dist-name2` I like this simplicity. You can also do #1 method, `find -name ...` but I assume they are the same thing.